# Word count group by window

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a Structured Streaming program that counts words:

```
#1
var inputTable = spark.readStream.format("kafka")
      .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "XX.XX.XXX.XX:9092")
      .option("subscribe", "topic-name")
      .option("startingOffsets", "earliest")
      .load()

#2
val df = inputTable.select(explode(split($"value".cast("string"), "\\s+")).as("word"))
  .groupBy($"word")
  .count

#3
val query = df.select($"word", $"count").writeStream.outputMode("complete").format("console").start()

#4
query.awaitTermination()
```

Now I want to window it by event time (there is a "timestamp" column in the input table).

So I need to change #2. I've tried:

```
val df = inputTable.select(explode(split($"value".cast("string"), "\\s+")).as("word"), "timestamp")
      .groupBy(window($"timestamp", "1 minute", $"word"))
      .count
```

But obviously the compiler complains that select method does not match the method signature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All arguments need to be of type `Column`

This should work (replaced `"timestamp"` with `col("timestamp")` in `select`) :

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val df = inputTable.select(explode(split($"value".cast("string"), "\\s+")).as("word"), col("timestamp"))
  .groupBy(window($"timestamp", "1 minute", $"word"))
  .count
```